# Java Vertical layout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, vertical-scrolling

I cannot solve the following two problems.

**PROBLEM 1**

I have a `JScrollPane` type panel, which is hosting a `JPanel`. The `JPanel`, during the execution of the program, receives more and more sub-Panels to host, due to which its height progressively increases (it is using a flow layout manager). What I want, and can't manage to achieve, is to make the `JScrollPane` panel show the vertical slide bar when the content of the `JPanel`  becomes higher than the window (due to the addition of many components).

So far I have managed to make methods by which the user can add sub-panels to the `JPanel`. But, when they become too many, and some of them get out of the screen, the vertical slide bar do not appear. How can I make them do so?

Kindly note that I would like the window width to be reseizable. Whenerver the window gets resized, the `JPanel` should recalculate its height, and adjust the slides consequently.

**PROBLEM 2**

In the `JPanel` I told you about in problem 1 I was using a flow layout manager, which sets up the components in horizontal lines. However, I would prefer to have a vertical disposition, which should add all components one right underneath the other, and not in a centered like disposition. They should look like this:

```
O============O
|COMP.1===   |
|COMP.2=     |
|COMP.3===== |
|            |
|            |
O============O
```

and not like this:

```
O============O
|COMP.1===   |
|            |
|COMP.2=     |
|            |
|COMP.3===== |
O============O
```

What's the best layout manager to obtain this final disposition, while keeping compatibility to the solution of problem 1? (which means, while adjusting the height of the `JPanel` after addition of each component?)

**Thank you so much in advance for your help!**

Comment: You can use `GridBagLayout`, with a little tweaking, will do the job or `VerticalLayout` from SwingLabs, SwingX libraries

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a hardcore user of swing but having worked with it last couple of months I would suggest using [MIGLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). It is very versatile and allows you to make layouts very easy. It takes a little time to learn, but it will make many layout problems very easy, e g forms.

Your problem could be solved like this with MIGLayout:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new MigLayout("gap rel 0", "grow"));
```

Panels can then be added like this:

```
panel.add(new JPanel(), "wrap");
```

Answer (score 0):

> However, I would prefer to have a vertical disposition, which should add all components one right underneath the other,

Sounds like a `BoxLayout` should do the trick. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on all the Swing layouts.

> and not in a centered like disposition.

If you have problems with alignment then don't forget to read the section on [Fixing Alignment Problems](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment).